# Ipfs & Orbitdb version compatibility issues with React App

Tags: ipfs, orbitdb

Recently i used ipfs@0.33.0 , ipfs-pubsub-room@1.4.1 . orbitdb@0.19.9 packages in nodejs application. It works fine and all packages integrated successfuly and worked perfectly.
But due to business logic i need to shift on React, for this i use
ipfs@0.33.0 , ipfs-pubsub-room@1.4.1 . orbitdb@0.19.9 versions but ipfs gives error "There is already a transport with this key" ... I tried to resolve but failed.
Then i switched to ipfs@0.34.4 (latest) , ipfs-pubsub-room@1.4.1 . orbitdb@0.19.9  versions it resolved "There is already a transport with this key"  error but when create orbitdb by using `let db = await orbitdb.keyvalue("orderbook3", access);`
it throws error " Arguments to path.join must be strings" .

I think there is only version compatibility issues regarding ipfs and orbitdb. Suggestions are required

Answer (score 0):

BY using updated version of orbitDB 0.20.0-rc1 . Problem fixed.